# New>Generic problem in Eclipse Helios no other attributes

Tags: eclipse-plugin

When I am trying to use eclipse Helios for plug-in development,I am not getting any attributes beside generic in any new RCL option. I have gone through net and found to download the source code but there is no way to append the same in Helios. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources** via Eclipse update site

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do it is:

1. Download the helios version for RCP developers from the eclipse web site.
2. Open target platform from the preferences menu.
3. Click "add" to add a new target platform.
4. "Nothing" is chosen for default target platform creation. Click next
5. On the new window click on the locations tab.. Click add , on the pop up window click directory and browse the plugin directory of eclipse for RCP developers (This version of helios includes the necessary plugin sources inside) and click finish
6. On the "implicit dependencies" tab show all the plugins added (choose all plugins)
   and then click finish and close the wizard window.
7. Finally choose the new target platform configuration you have just created.

Now you can see all the new attributes beside generics (related to the plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Download the SDK plugins from:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3/